# Redirect to ~/Shared/Error.cshtml from Controller's method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 app with Visual Studio 2015, C# and .NET Framework 4.6.1.

I have a controller with this method:

```
public ActionResult Error(string message)
{
    ViewBag.Message = message;
    return View();
}
```

Now it shows a custom view on folder `~/Views/MyController/Error.cshtml`. Note: I created that view doing right click on method's name, and selecting `Add view...` option.

But I want to use a common `Error.cshtml` view for all my errors. This view will be on `~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml`.

How can I do it?

By the way, I have also enabled CustomErrors on Web.Config.

Comment: Just delete your Error.cshtml from ~/Views/MyController and it will use Error.cshtml from ~/View/Shared/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ViewEngine` searches for the View in the following locations:

```
~/Views/ControllerName/ActionName.cshtml
~/Views/ControllerName/ActionName.vbhtml
~/Views/ControllerName/ActionName.aspx
~/Views/ControllerName/ActionName.ascx
```

and

```
~/Views/Shared/ActionName.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/ActionName.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/ActionName.aspx
~/Views/Shared/ActionName.ascx
```

The View name is the Action name by default, unless you specify the View. So if you just omit `Error.cshtml` file in your `~/Views/MyController` it should find it in your shared folder: `~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml`